# Prevent Error Log display to the public

Tags: security

Whenever we rebuild the catalog_product_flat index, Magento displays its standard error page along with a stack trace that reveals file structure to the outside world.

How do I stop this?

I've tried Googling "magento prevent display errors" but did not find anything relevant.

It doesn't seem to matter whether I comment the `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` line or these lines:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}
```

I also added this to the index.php file, to no avail:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

I still want these errors logged in the var/reports folder, though.

Comment: Did you set `MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE` in `.htaccess`? If so, make sure your webserver allows setting custom global vars from within .htaccess. Some environments do not allow to do so, especially FCGI envs. But there are workarounds by putting a prefix to the vars.

Comment: Reports will always be written by Magento anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to rename file **errors/local.xml.sample** to **errors/local.xml** in site document root. Then change node `<action>print</action>` to `<action>email</action>` and put your email in node `<email_address>your_email@example.com</email_address>`. 
All reports will be sent to this email.

Comment: And what if I don't want the errors emailed either? Printing them is obviously a security risk. But emailing them has resulted in throttling from Gmail when our server has sent out thousands of these emails to us. Why not just log them and be done with it?

Comment: Feel free to use  `<action>none</action>` It doesn't print exeption trace or send email (**none**  taken out of the blue, just use a value other than **print** or **email**)